# Vim filetype not properly set when text in file is starting with "#", therfore syntax is not properly highlighted

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, file-type

I created a dedicated syntax file
.vim/syntax/foo.vim

and I would like to apply this syntax file for all files having the coresponding ending  "myfile.foo"

For doing this, I added the following line in the .vimrc

`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.foo setf foo`

this is perfectly working, but...

If the text inside the file is starting with a "#", a different filetype is applied:
filetype=conf

I can override this by using :set filetype=foo to get my desired type.

It is a bit annoying and I don't know how can I overcome this workaround.

Comment: I just used the ending "abc" as example. Maybe not a good idea, because I wasn't aware about that this filetype exists.

Comment: Updated the question according your suggestion, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not put anything to your vimrc!**

Insert your command into `~/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim` instead.

The point is that your command must get into `filetypedetect` auto-group, otherwise any subsequent `:filetype detect` will overwrite your filetype to the defaults.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this was solving the issue